# Why does sleep() cause a new line?

Tags: c++, operating-system

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    while(1){
        int temp = rand();
        int mod = temp % 7;
        for(int i=0; i<mod; i++){
            std::cout<<temp<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
        //usleep(90000);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am curious why if you uncomment usleep(9000) there are extra newlines being printed vs sleep(1).

[image: this is the output when you uncomment usleep(9000)]

Comment: It's not the `sleep` that does it - it's synchronization.

Comment: Why do you think it's the sleep that's doing it?  Sometimes `temp % 7` will be `0`.

Comment: [Here's my output](https://i.imgur.com/3gWWX7a.png) with the line commented and newlines still in there.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Synchronisation with what?

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I sometimes express myself in cryptic ways although that is never my intention. 1201ProgramAlarm said it much better.

Comment: @TedLyngmo So, it's not synchronization at all. Is it possible you only glanced at the question, thought it had multiple threads, and are now trying to walk it back? ;)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I actually don't remember anything regarding this question or even making the comment. Too much wine :-) When I looked at it now I assumed I meant the same as 1201 but used the wrong words.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Barefoot Merlot will get ya good :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has nothing to do with sleeping.

When `rand()` returns a value dividable by 7, the value of `mod` is 0.

The `for` loop is not executed, but a new line break is still being output after the loop.

```
std::cout<<"\n";
```

You can debug the result by using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(){
    while(1){
        int temp = rand();
        int mod = temp % 7;
        std::cout<<"["<<mod<<"]";
        for(int i=0; i<mod; i++){
            std::cout<<temp<<" ";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n";
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
 }
```